# Class Get Function Error ByRef

Tags: vba, excel, class, get

I have a custom class called a `cCavity`. One of the many properties of the class is a string array called `pAdjacency`, which contains the string name of a node at each index (Format is C[# of Node]). I am trying to create edge names by using two node names in conjunction with one another. Whenever I try to call the adjacency `GET` function for the class objects, I get a ByRef argument type mismatch, and I cannot see why.

Class Get function:

```
Public Property Get Adjacency(Index As Integer) As String
    Adjacency = pAdjacency(Index)
End Property
```

Section of Code that is getting an error:

```
Sub CalculateEdges(cCavities() As cCavity, dEdges As Scripting.Dictionary)
    'Dim i as integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(cCavities)
        If cCavities(i).AdjacencySize > MaxEdges Then MaxEdges = cCavities(i).AdjacencySize
        'Dim j as Integer
        For j = 1 To cCavities(i).AdjacencySize
            dEdges.Add cCavities(i).Name & cCavities(i).Adjacency(j), 0 ' The error is taking place here, with the .Adjacency(j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

The error in question is: "Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch"

Am I missing something obvious? The argument j should be an integer, and I have tried explicitly defining it as such while trying to figure out what was happening.

Comment: Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, and declare *all* identifiers with an explicit type. Removing them "to make the code text shorter" is outright ludicrous.

Comment: Also, where _exactly_ is the code failing, what is the error number and exact wording?

Comment: No, I removed it from the block of code that I placed on the site here to make it shorter. It is currently commented out in the source code on my end because I am trying various methods to get it to work. Since it was not uncommented at the time of posting, I did not include it.

Comment: @Excelosaurus I will add a comment in the original post on the line, with an error number in the text below.

Comment: What type is `cCavity.AdjacencySize`?

Comment: in the Main, I declare the `Edges` dictionary with: `Set Edges = New Scripting.Dictionary` while the Cavities array is pulled from an excel sheet and instantiated during a form. I can get values out of the Cavities array just fine earlier in the program.

Comment: That code smells like it wants `Cavities` (please drop that `c` prefix) to be a proper *collection class*, and wants an `Adjacencies` collection class too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First specify `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables, then make your parameters `ByVal` where it makes sense: object pointers and values can be passed by value, arrays must be passed `ByRef`.

So start with this:

```
Public Property Get Adjacency(ByVal Index As Long) As String
    Adjacency = pAdjacency(Index)
End Property
```

Now, that 4-liner snippet is dereferencing `cCavities(i)` 5 times. Have you considered introducing a local variable, and dereferencing the object *once*?

```
For i = LBound(cCavities) To UBound(cCavities)
    Dim foo As cCavity
    Set foo = cCavities(i)
    For j = 1 To foo.AdjacencySize
        Dim edge As String
        edge = foo.Name & foo.Adjacency(j)
    Next
Next
```

Now, does that `foo` assignment work? If so, congrats, you now have *IntelliSense* on the `cCavity` member calls, and more efficient code.

Comment: I have realized that I had another error, since fixed, that was happening later in the code (another section that is commented out and was not included) , and that the commenting I had of dim j was the error in this particular case. I mistook the two separate errors for the same one when I posted the question, but have since realized my error.

Comment: Removing explicit declarations is **never** a good fix for anything.

Comment: I was simply trying anything that came to mind at the time. I don't know what else to say.

Comment: @Mat'sMug is there a to pass a parameter to `Property Get Foo` and still have  `Property Let Foo`?

Comment: @ThomasInzina yes, that's an *indexed property*. The last parameter of the `Property Let/Set` procedure must be the RHS assignment argument, and all other parameters must match between the `Get` and `Let/Set` signatures (otherwise you get a compile error for mismatched accessor signatures)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I wish I could convince my employer to let me install anything that would help, or let me use a language that is not VBA. I did not chose this setup or this situation, and as of now I am only passively familiar with VBA.

Comment: It seems like an unnecessary limitation.   Of course, when the VBA was written computers were a lot slower and I'm sure language architecture has improved.

Comment: @ThomasInzina not sure how it can be considered a limitation... If you get an item with an index, it only makes sense to set that item with an index too.

Comment: I suppose you're right.  My thought is that you could have an option of assigning all the values at once.  I guess you'd be better off writing a separate procedure to for that.

Answer (score 1):

It's a compile error, not a run-time error. If j is a Variant (as it will be if it's not explicitly declared), the compiler won't let it through. Declare all of your variables with their proper types.

**Edit**: for some reason, the compiler only complains about this at run-time, but it's still a compile error.

Comment: That's what I thought too, which is why I had it explicitly declared at first to be an Integer. I only have it commented out in this particular snapshot of the code because that was the way I had it at the time I decided to make a post.

Comment: It's the ByVal that'll make the difference, as per @Mat's Mug answer. VBA's arguments are passed ByRef by default. I'm so used to type ByVal that I hadn't noticed.